# LogFormat для GoAccess

Tags: логирование

Есть лог с nginx формат:

`'$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'"$request" $status $bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$uid_got" "$uid_set" $msec '
'adfr="$cookie_adfr" '
'dv="$cookie_dv" dvr="$cookie_dvr" '
'lv="$cookie_lv" lvr="$cookie_lvr" '
'rt=$request_time ut="$upstream_response_time" '
'cs=$upstream_cache_status ua="$upstream_addr" us="$upstream_status"'`

Логи получается такие:

```
10.41.32.104 - - [18/Sep/2017:00:00:02 +0300] "GET /breaking/current/?project_id=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 206 "-" "python-requests/2.13.0" "-" "-" 1505682002.098 adfr="-" dv="-" dvr="-" lv="-" lvr="-" rt=0.000 ut="-" cs=HIT ua="-" us="-"
10.16.32.116 - - [18/Sep/2017:00:00:02 +0300] "GET /clusters/info?rubricator_id=1&ids=37189260 HTTP/1.1" 200 2961 "-" "python-requests/2.13.0" "-" "-" 1505682002.133 adfr="-" dv="-" dvr="-" lv="-" lvr="-" rt=0.151 ut="0.151" cs=MISS ua="10.16.20.25:8084" us="200"
```

Вот конфиг goaccess

`log-format %h %^ - [%d:%t] "%r" %s %b %^ "%u" %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %T
date-format %d/%b/%Y
time-format %H:%M:%S %z`

Все хорошо, только почему-то goaccess никак не хочет находить `$response_time`

Подскажите, что надо поправить в goaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Удалилось решить проблему:

`log-format %h %^ - [%d:%t] "%r" %s %b %^ "%u" %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^=%T ^%
date-format %d/%b/%Y
time-format %H:%M:%S %z`